# Can you add data to a binary, without affecting its jump labels?

Tags: disassembly, binary-editing

I'm a total beginner, so I don't know the vocabulary yet to search effectively. What I want to do is add some data (let's say level data), to an old game ROM, but that would probably shift all the jump labels by the amount of bytes I added.

I thought about disassembling the ROM, finding its starting point and parsing my way through the jump instructions to find all (absolute) labels and tweak them after I know where and how much data I added.

Is that feasible/practical and are there tools for such an operation already?

Comment: You can look for unused sections of the code/data and add it there.

Comment: Please add some more details, so that we can answer your question more precisely. What is the file format - `ELF`, `PE`, ...? How much is that game complicated (effectiveness of your approach depends highly on that)?